# VB.NET: How do you display a 'You are protected' message, even after you've closed the program?

Tags: vb.net, antivirus

I have an anti-virus program which I'm developing.

I've noticed that with a lot of anti-viruses, it gives you a first-time alert saying: 'Please perform a first scan', and then when you click the scan button, the 'Please perform a first scan' message goes away, and changes to 'You are protected'.

I know how to do this with a simple `.Hide` line of code, but how do you make it so when you next open the program, the message is still 'You are protected'.

This is my code:

```
Public Class Mainframe
Private Sub FlatButton1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
        PictureBox2.Hide()
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Label2.Text = "Awesome!"
        Label3.Text = "You are protected."
        Label3.Location = New Point(453, 152)
        FlatButton1.Hide() '22
        FlatButton2.Location = New Point(453, 229) '21
        PictureBox3.Show()
        PictureBox3.Location = New Point(218, 115)
        Label2.Location = New Point(341, 152)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FlatButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton2.Click
        ScanPage.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

> I'm a bit of a newbie to this Stackoverflow questioning feature, so my apologies if I didn't explain it well, no excuse though. If you need any additional information, just comment below.

Comment: You need to have something that indicates whether you've performed a first scan or not. This also needs to be stored on the disk so that it persists after a system shutdown/restart. You could for instance store the date of the latest scan, and if its value is, say, [**`DateTime.MinValue`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) then a scan has never been performed. Look into [**My.Settings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object).

Comment: Most anti-virus programs never really exit.  The UI closes, but there is always a service running in the background that does the actual protecting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use streamwriter to write scan summary in disk and streamreader to read at window loading.
This help you to identify whether system already  performed scan or not.

Otherwise option of window service also helpful in case of antivirus.